# fgetc is giving me incorrect character

Tags: c

I wrote a program that opens a diff file and is supposed to parse through the output.  However, I can't even get to the parsing part of the algorithm.  I decided to open the diff file in my main to troubleshoot what my first character in the stream is, and it doesn't match what is in the file.  The first character in the file is '1', but when I run the code below, I get 49.  I have no idea what has gone wrong.  Can anyone guide me?  Thank you in advance.

```
    FILE *diff = fopen(diff_filename,"r");

    int what;
    what = fgetc(diff);
    fprintf (stderr,"%d\n",what);
```

I tried to cast the output to a char variable, it still remains 49.

Comment: 49 is the int value of the ascii for '1'.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do comparisons work the same way if I compare it with a number? Or do I have to convert the ascii into a character?  I'm not new to programming, I'm just very very new to C.

Comment: can you add this property `char c = what;` then print the value with `printf("%c",c);` and check the output?

Comment: printf won't output to stderr.  I have to use fprintf.  But I think I kind of understand.  fputc shows it is the correct character.  I guess the next question is if I do int number = fgetc(diff), does it store the value as 1 or 49?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fpritnf()` format string is wrong.  If you want a character representation it should be:

```
    fprintf (stderr,"%c\n",what);
```

Comment: Yes I see.  When I go to comparisons, does if (what == 1) work?  or do I need to do if ((char)what ==1)? or if ((char)what == '1')?

Comment: A char is just a number that represents a character (in most cases a unicode character), '1' just happens to be 49. If you want to compare it then do `if (what == '1')` no need to cast a char into a char because it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you.  Let's say I wanted to compare it with a range of numbers.  What would be the way to do that?  I tried doublecasting it, it does not work. if ((((int)((char)current_c) >=0)) && (((int)((char)current_c))<= 9))

Comment: You're are better of asking a new question instead of a discussion in comments.  If you want to check if `what` is a digit use ctype.h's `isdigit()`.  If you want to do it yourself it would be `if(what >= '0' && what <= '9')`

Comment: Sorry, one more question, my code uses multiplication to to determine if the number is more than 1 digit.  I do this by multiplying by 10 and then adding the next found number.  How would I multiply it?

Comment: so potential_sum = what-'0', then potential_sum = (potential_sum *10) + new_what will work?  I'm sorry if this seems very inane.  I wrote over 700 lines of code because I know a lot of Java, but apparently I don't know anything about C basics.

Comment: `sum = 10 * sum + what - '0'` and you have to check that `what` is a digit before doing it.  You could also use `strtol()`, or `sscanf()`.